# Configuration.GetSection returns a ConfigurationSection that doesn't exists in the file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm working with a .NET Framework application that contains lines like these:

```cs
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
Console.WriteLine(configuration.FilePath);
var mySettings = (MySettings) configuration.GetSection("MySettings");
```

It prints the following path:

```
C:\Users\Daniel Jonsson\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyApp.exe_Url_ib5gv4f20ng5kujpcanm3fusbnakfvor\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

However, that file doesn't contain a section `MySettings`. Instead, the `MySettings` section that is being read is found in program's .config file in `C:\code\MyCompany\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe.config`.

Is there some sort inheritance between the configuration files that control this behavior? Or why does it behave like this? I would like it to read whatever is in the `user.config` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `Configuration` class represents a merged view of the configuration settings from all of the configuration files, according to this [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):

> Configuration settings are stored in a hierarchy of configuration files. The Configuration class instance represents the merged view of the configuration settings from all of the configuration files that apply to a specific physical entity, such as a computer, or to a logical entity, such as an application or a Web site. The logical entity can exist on the local computer or on a remote server. For information about configuration files, see Configuring Apps and ASP.NET Configuration Files.

The hierarchy is as follows, according to this [source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#t1_1):

> `Machine.config` > `[AppName.exe.config]` > `Roaming.config` > `User.config`

When using `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal`, it will merge all of those levels, according to this section of the previous [source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#t2_1):

> Remember that configuration is hierarchical and merged. When requesting roaming or local user configuration, that level up through machine.config are merged, resulting in the complete configuration accessible by your application for the given user level. An interesting consequence of this merging allows you to request roaming or local user configuration even when the User.config file does not exist. The Configuration object returned will contain a FilePath that does not exist and the HasFile property will be false. Any sections defined in higher configuration levels will still be accessible though and with the proper allowances, changes to those sections can be saved. Saving changes at a level that previously did not exist will create the appropriate User.config file.